# Understanding kubernetes port forwarding, port and targetPort

Tags: kubernetes, portforwarding

So, this is my understanding that `port` is the port on which a service serves requests and `targetPort` is the port where your app within the container servers requests.

`targetPort` is not even required to be specified, it is usually the same as `containerPort` (I got this from a `StackOverflow` answer and I verified it by removing `targetPort`)

Kubernetes port forwarding forwards the request received on local port to the remote port (where the service runs). [I have been following this article to understand this better](https://kubernetesbyexample.com/pf/)

In my application, the specs were created using `helm`. My `port` is set to `80` and my `containerPort` is set to `5000` (It is a very simple Flask app).

Following the example mentioned in that link the following should work:

```
kubectl --namespace default port-forward $POD_NAME 7000:80
```

but this one works instead:

```
kubectl --namespace default port-forward $POD_NAME 7000:5000
```

Is there something I've not understood correctly? Here's the `kubectl describe` of my pod:

```
Name:           mock-python-server-9f5b557f5-klxq8
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           docker-desktop/192.168.65.3
Start Time:     Thu, 21 Jan 2021 13:59:40 -0800
Labels:         app.kubernetes.io/instance=mock-python-server
                app.kubernetes.io/name=mock-python-server
                pod-template-hash=9f5b557f5
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             10.1.2.39
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mock-python-server-9f5b557f5
Containers:
  master:
    Container ID:   docker://7e258d94c458f47c1add418c7969e77fbaa532c56df7405681e778d5f0e63d01
    Image:          <image>
    Image ID:       <image_id>
    Port:           5000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 21 Jan 2021 13:59:43 -0800
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  128Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   128Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:http/health delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get http://:http/health delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      env:  LOCAL
...
```

Here's a snippet from `deployment.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "master.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "master.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "master.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        {{- include "master.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
    {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}

      serviceAccountName: {{ include "master.serviceAccountName" . }}
      securityContext:
        {{- toYaml .Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          env:
            - name: env
              value: {{ .Values.environment }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 5000 #{{ .Values.flaskPort }}
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: http
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
```

and my `service.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "master.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "master.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: 80 #{{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: 5000
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    {{- include "master.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using port-forwarding, it tunnel to a specified resource inside your cluster, so the command `kubectl --namespace default port-forward $POD_NAME 7000:80`, mean you want to connect to a resource named `$POD_NAME` from your localhost port 7000 to the resource on port 80

And from your description, you actually dont want to connect to a pod but to a service (which point to the pod you want on port 5000 when there is a request from port 80 inside your cluster). So you need to specify the service name in your command, like this:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/{{your service name}} 7000:80
```

Comment: I actually do have those. I just posted my full spec in the question

Comment: Oh, so you want to port forward to a service, is it correct ? Try this
`kubectl port-forward svc/{{your service name}} 7000:80`

Comment: ...this worked!! So, what happens in the earlier command when I do not mention `service/my-service` ? And why does it successfully only forward from `7000` on my local port to `5000` on the container?

Answer (score 2):

Your kubernetes(k8s) app is listening on its container port: 5000 , so to be able to access from your machine you do:

```
 kubectl --namespace default port-forward $POD_NAME 7000:5000
```

that will allow you to connect outside k8s to your app on port 7000

Your app listening  port is set somewhere to 5000 , not to 80 ...

Comment: I just added the spec - could check that out?